# Why can TypeScript's compiler not analyze an array of types?

Tags: typescript

**Setup:** Given some typescript code like:

```
type ObjectList = {
  [index: string]: string;
};

function makeList(input: ObjectList | string | number): string[] {
  if (typeof input === "string" || typeof input === "number") {
    return [String(input)];
  }
  const arr = [];
  for (const x in input) {
    arr.push(String(input[x]));
  }
  return arr;
}

// Turns a number into a string array
console.log(makeList(123));

// Turns a string into an array
console.log(makeList("hello"));

// Turns an object dictionary into an array
console.log(makeList({ a: "A", b: "B" }));
```

Ok, simple enough, and it works fine. Critical to type safety is this line:

```
if (typeof input === "string" || typeof input === "number") {
```

It ensures that the `for in` will only operate on the `ObjectList`, and the TypeScript compiler does a great job of sniffing that out for us! The downside here is how verbose that line of code is, especially if you were to add more types, alternatively it seems we should be able to do this:

```
if (['string', 'number'].includes(typeof input)) {
```

However, this will result in a TypeScript compiler error basically indicating the `for loop` is not sure that the `string` and `number` types cannot reach it.

> The right-hand side of a 'for...in' statement must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter, but here has type 'string | number | ObjectList

Here's a running example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-arrayincludestypeof-var-dblkn?file=/src/index.ts

**Question:** In an effort to understand the compiler better — I'm interested in why the compiler exhibits this behavior. What about the `[].includes()` is incompatible with the compiler? Is the static analysis too deep? Are there runtime considerations I'm not thinking of? Is there some additional "magic" bound into the `typeof` operator in TS when used in comparisons?

Comment: "Is the static analysis too deep?" Yes. If typescript had to check the values of every array and keep in mind the logic of every function that operates on those arrays, it'd be way slower.

Comment: I'm curious - does adding an `any` typecast fix the issue? As in, would this work?
`if (['string', 'number'].includes(typeof (input as any))) {`

Comment: Typescript does analysis when you have an if statement to narrow the types, but it only does this on a very basic level. You can define your own function to narrow the types if you need something more complex - this feature is called type guards see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: If you want typesafe guarantees for your code, don't mutate your arrays. TS does not like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you directly check `typeof input === "string"`, the compiler treats this as a *type guard* which has implications on the apparent type of `input`.  Whereas before the check, `input` is known only to be of its declared type (e.g., `ObjectList | string | number`), after the check it is possible for the compiler to give it a *narrower*, *apparent* type in areas of code that can only be reached if the check returns `true` (e.g., `string`), and another such apparent type in areas of code that can only be reached if the check returns `false` (e.g., `ObjectList | number`).  This is called [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).

Such control flow analysis does not work by simulating the behavior of the code on all possible inputs and giving `input` the union of all possible values it can take.  It also does not work via intuition and intellect; the compiler is unable to simply "understand" that some block of code is reachable if and only if some variables are narrower than their declared types.  Instead, there are a bunch of specific *heuristics* that have been implemented, corresponding to distinct identifiable and common coding patterns known to be used as type guards.

Treating `typeof someVariable === "string"` as a type guard is one such heuristic, [the `typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards).

But `["string"].includes(typeof someVariable)` is *not* treated as a type guard by the compiler; nobody has implemented such a thing.

---

An interesting discussion about a similar question/suggestion can be found at [microsoft/TypeScript#36275](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275):  Why doesn't TypeScript treat `Array.includes()` or `Array.indexOf()` as a type guard?

As @RyanCavanaugh (development lead for the TypeScript team at Microsoft) said [in a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36275#issuecomment-702233949):

> [The lack of type guard] is the behavior absent the implementation of a feature that would cause it behave the way the OP is proposing. None of the existing narrowing mechanics apply here; we're talking about probably a thousand lines of new code to *correctly* detect and narrow arrays based on these methods, along with a performance penalty paid by every program because the control flow graph would have to be more granular to set up the possible narrowings caused by any method call, along with a bug trail and confusion trail caused by people expecting non-method versions of these functions to also behave the same way.

I imagine the same would be said for this case; implementing this type guard in the compiler would take a lot of work, make the compiler slower for everyone, and introduce more complexity and possible bugs, all for the benefit of supporting a relatively uncommon use case.

---

Luckily, though, TypeScript does give developers the ability to write their own custom type guards via [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  You need to refactor your intended type guard into a `boolean`-returning function that acts upon one of its parameters, which means that you still won't get `["string"].includes(typeof input)` to work out-of-the-box, but you can at least get closer.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
interface TypeofMap {
  string: string;
  number: number;
  bigint: bigint;
  boolean: boolean;
  symbol: symbol;
  undefined: undefined;
  object: object | null;
  function: Function
}
function typeofIncludes<K extends keyof TypeofMap>(typeofs: K[], val: any): val is TypeofMap[K];
function typeofIncludes(typeofs: Array<keyof TypeofMap>, val: any) {
  return typeofs.includes(typeof val);
}
```

I've defined a `TypeofMap` interface whose only purpose is to represent the mapping between the string values returned by the JS `typeof` operator and the TypeScript types they represent.  It's not perfect; there is no such TypeScript type as a "non-function object" corresponding to the `"object"` string, and rather than trying to simulate one I just use `object`.

Then the `typeofIncludes()` function takes an array `typeofs` of `typeof`-outputtable strings and a value `val`, and returns a `boolean` value which is `true` if `val` is one of the relevant types.

You can test it out here:

```
function makeList(input: ObjectList | string | number): string[] {
  if (typeofIncludes(["string", "number"], input)) {
    return [String(input)];
  }
  const arr = [];
  for (const x in input) {
    arr.push(String(input[x]));
  }
  return arr;
}
```

This works.  Inside the "then" clause of `if (typeofIncludes(["string", "number"], input))`, `input` has been narrowed to `string | number`, while in the "else" clause it has been narrowed to `ObjectList`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AGQJYGdhQLxQDeAUFFANoYB2AJhAB4BcUOATtQOYC6zbnA3MQC+g4tWARWAMwCGyaABVwEAPZSAsjLBFSLYOyode+gbqoBXALZxJzC9cmCycDB3HMXbqsCdQ4KlQAbCBkqDwDg0N8sEGsg3lj-QN9zWggpaggaZlS6DKos3xVEFGBmYqRUKAAfKAtA5N0pVNQMFTCoADEW4DaqYWJmqlb2qFBINQBJYcDzOiwAHgBpKAYJWiwoAGsIEDUoJQmNLQA+AApx1SksZiXyLgAaKAA3GUDmUJAASmZXwKhsAdlGpNGByEsuIIhiMqGNgVJpshZvMLvCblAAIKsVgyEALHZ7KRAo6gk5PP4fKjfHRkVgQYDmViwy5qLAAOmoSLmECwqKOLzeX0EQmIgx6fSglhkO0wODO1DA5jKsBKqFluFqfEMNTqVhsrB+egMHHuNIBRL5V0RyJ5Z3IACItRx7U97fZ9fbHgCqIrgF8vmbafTGbDyABlEyGeU+pVfSG6EVkZDtHBQGTY-AUeNkKQqVhQM7Jqip+je72+gMkMhkdOsNmKrAACzOEeN0d95HoXH9vkTUDpDKZaexwtFAHoxwcQ5sZLqHPnxCo00bOMOcSBiEWsEEIGzAioOGcpTLsMAzgBGABMAGYe+PJwpp8und7gEvQmvcZuUzu9wej9KEDqmc9qNhADQqPad7EBOU5MjOsIVKUUA0BgMLpiAr7vrCtZfluv77oex5AaeZyEGmzD2hiLp+JRABC9pQEId5AA)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than asking what about your code is "incompatible", it is more enlightening to ask what makes a check like `typeof input === 'number'` work, and then we can see that the same mechanism does not apply to the `includes` condition.

Quoting from the [Typescript manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards):

> `typeof` type guards are recognized in two different forms: `typeof v === "typename"` and `typeof v !== "typename"`, where `"typename"` can be one of `typeof` operator’s return values (`"undefined"`, `"number"`, `"string"`, `"boolean"`, `"bigint"`, `"symbol"`, `"object"`, or `"function"`).

So the condition `typeof input === 'number'` allows control-flow type narrowing because the language specifically does type narrowing for conditions of this specific form. The Typescript docs list all the specific forms of conditions which allow type narrowing:

- User-defined type guards, i.e. functions with an `arg is Type` return type.
- `keyName in obj`
- `typeof obj === 'typename'`
- `obj instanceof ClassName`
- Eliminating `null` and/or `undefined` from unions by checking for equality or truthiness.

And that's it. So the reason `['string', 'number'].includes(typeof input)` doesn't do type narrowing is simply because this condition is not of one of the specific forms that the compiler recognises.